# Issue with code related to deltatime in python

Tags: python, datetime

The following code's aim was to convert a date to corresponding day. I took 2nd October 2017 as the reference and hence proceeded. I don't entirely understand deltatime and guessing the problem might be with how I used it. Hope someone could help me.

```
import datetime
ans = 'Y'
today = datetime.date(2017, 10, 2)
while ans is 'Y' or ans is 'y':
    d = input("Enter a date (DD/MM/YYYY)")
    day = int(d[:2])
    month = int(d[3:5])
    year = int(d[6:])
    thatday = datetime.date(year, month, day)
    deltat = thatday - today
    dif = int(deltat.days/7)
    if dif is 6:
        print("Sunday")
    elif dif is 1:
        print("Tuesday")
    elif dif is 2:
        print ("Wednesday")
    elif dif is 3:
        print("Thursday")
    elif dif is 4:
        print("Friday")
    elif dif is 5:
        print("Saturday")
    else:
        print("Monday")
    ans = input("One more time, eh? (y/n)")
```

Comment: Hi! Good to see you tried!!! +1, You are missing some "basic" knowledge about time in Python like the usage of the function strptime(). I can provide something if you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I started of trying to help you but got lost when I didn't really understood what you need.

Basically I think you need to read about strftime which prints a datetime object in a specific way: e.g. datetime.strftime("%A") gives weekday. You also need strptime which reads a date from a string, e.g. datetime.strptime("31/12/1999","%d/%m/%Y")

Look at your modified code below:

```
import datetime
ans = 'Y'
today = datetime.datetime.now().date()

while ans.title() == 'Y':
    d = input("Enter a date (DD/MM/YYYY)")
    thatday = datetime.datetime.strptime(d,"%d/%m/%Y").date()
    deltat = thatday - today # timedelta
    dif = int(deltat.days/7) # timedelta/7? What is this?
    print(thatday.strftime("%A")) # Here you get the weekday of thatday
    ans = input("One more time, eh? (y/n)")
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I just realized, I used '/' instead of '%'.

Answer (score 0):

if you're just looking for the day of the week you can also do this. The weekday() returns an integer value, with Monday being 0 and Sunday being 6

```
from datetime import *
weekdays = ['Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday','Sunday']
d = date(2017, 10, 2).weekday()
print(weekdays[d])
```

That date returns Monday

Comment: I just realized I made an inane mistake that ruined the code. got it corrected now, but, it never hurts to get another perspective, right?  Thanks

Comment: Just a comment: date(2017, 10, 2).strftime("%A")) does the same thing as I've examplified above, meaning you don't need to use a list.